# External Harddrive is showing in System Information but not Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, system-information

My harddrive crashed last night and since then I have not been able to access it on my Macbook Pro. I've restarted both my computer and hardrive multiple times and I've experienced the same result. It does not show up on my desktop (yes, external disks is checked in finder preferences) nor in Disk Utility but it shows up in System Information. The harddrive is also still blinking its light per usual and has not made any abnormal sounds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same problem. Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Could be either a bad hard drive, in which case the enclosure still functions properly and is recognized by System Information, or a failed enclosure in that it's not communicating properly with the hard drive.

Comment: Restart with CMD-R !

Answer (score 1):

So I know this was asked a very long time ago but for the sake of people landing on this page, here's what I know:

If it shows up in system utility and your drive is spinning (as mine is), that means your hard drive enclosure is functioning and the logic board inside is working as well. However, if it's not showing up in the disk utility then there is still an internal problem with the hard drive. Since it is at least partially functioning, it may be possible for a professional to be able to recover some or all of the data from the drive but you'll probably need to invest in a new one for future use. Sorry.